# Can I inject specific parameters with Ninject when a class is instantiated?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject

For the sake of this example, I have a "User" class that needs to receive access to my EmailService.
Whenevera a new user instance is created  ( `var user = new User(emailServiceInstance);` ) I do not want EmailService instance to be included as a parameter because not all callers will be aware of it. I want Ninject to inject it.
So normally a binding for the EmailService would look something like this:

```
kernel.Bind<IEmailService>().To<EmailService>().InSingletonScope();
```

But I would like to include more parameters in my User class constructor. I would like to pass some parameters and have EmailService injected as well. Is this possible?
From its callers, User class would be instanciated with something like:

```
var user = new User(firstName,LastName, [notsure])
```

And then my User class constructor would look like this:

```
public User(string firstName, stringLastName, EmailService emailService)
```

First and Lastname would be passed in and email service would be instantiated/injected with Ninject.
Is it possible? What would be the correct syntax to create this binding ?

Comment: Instead of constructor injection you can use property injection

Comment: You should try to avoid mixing data and behaviour. Inject behaviour (known at design time) through the constructor and pass data (known at runtime) through method arguments. Your `User` class looks like it's trying to be both.

Answer (score 2):

Neither Constructor Injection nor Property Injection are a good fit for your scenario. In section 4.3 of [DIPP&P](https://mng.bz/BYNl), Mark Seemann and I state that:

> *Entities that contain behavior besides their usual set of data members would easily get a wide range of methods, each requiring their own dependencies. Although you might be tempted to use Constructor Injection to inject such dependencies, that leads to a situation where each such entity needs to be created with all of its dependencies, even though only a few may be necessary for a given use case. This complicates testing the logic of an entity, because all dependencies need to be supplied to the constructor, even though a test might only be interested in a few dependencies. Method Injection [...] offers a better alternative.*

Using Method Injection, your `User` entity would become something as follows:

```cs
public class User
{
    public string FirstName { get; }
    public string LastName { get; }
    
    public string PasswordHash { get; }

    public User(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        this.FirstName = firstName;
        this.LastName = lastName;
    }

    public void ResetPassword(
        IEmailService mailService, IPasswordGenerator generator)
    {
        var password = generator.Generate();
    
        this.PasswordHash = generator.Hash(password);
        
        // Warning: this is just an example, but not a good security practice.
        // Mailing passwords is a good way to be shamed on plaintextoffenders.com
        mailService.SendMail($@"
            Hello {this.FirstName}
            
            We have received new password request for your account.
            
            Your new password is: {password}.");
    }
}
```

Notice that the `ResetPassword` method does *not* store its incoming dependencies. This is deliberate and this is what makes Method Injection different from both Constructor Injection and Property Injection. When dependencies are applied to a class after construction (which is what happens with Property Injection), it leads to [Temporal Coupling](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/24/DesignSmellTemporalCoupling/). By letting the method *use* the dependency, but not *store* the dependency, it prevents Temporal Coupling from occurring.

A more detailed discussion about Method Injection and how to apply it to classes like entities can be found in section 4.3 of [Dependency Injection Principles, Practices, and Patterns](https://mng.bz/BYNl).